# Creating a matrix of plots in MATLAB, similar to plot matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, plot

I want to create a 3x3 matrix of plots in MATLAB where each element is a subplot of some corresponding 1000 samples (suppose values are stored in a 3x3x1000 matrix A). I want the subplots to be spaced very close together, and the y axis numbers/labels to only show up for the left subplots and the x axis numbers/labels to only show up for the bottom subplots.

For example, something similar to plotmatrix, except subplot ij would plot A(i,j,:).
[plotmatrix example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O1Cri.png)

Is there an easy way to do this in MATLAB? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The axes properties of the subplots can be modified to achieve this, but an easier way would be to use a FEX submission called [panel](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20003-panel). Have a look at its example output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This is exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

`subplot` can do that for you in MATLAB.

```
h = subplot(3,3,1)
```

Will split the current figure in a 3 x 3 matrix and creates an axes(area where you plot something) in the 1st cell of the matrix. `h` is the "handle" to the axes which you can then use to modify the xlabels and ylabels in any way.

Documentation for [`subplot`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html)

Documentation for [Axes](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axes-properties.html)